# Synonym request: multithreading / multi-threading / multi-threaded

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Requesting to merge tags:

- [multi-threading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-threading) × 19
- [multithreading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading)  × 5
- [multi-threaded](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-threaded)  × 4

I'd propose using [multithreading] as the master tag, as this is [what Wikipedia uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_%28computer_architecture%29), but I guess that's not really important -- important is to not have 3 different tags that say the same thing :-)

cheers!

Comment: I've suggested the synonyms now

Answer (score 4):

I like the [multithreading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) choice. Merge away!